# Why it won't apply changes when using Nginx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx

I've just switched from `Apache + Passenger` to `Nginx + Unicorn`

I used to command `/etc/init.d/httpd restart` after I added change.
Then all the changes used to be applied to Rails Application.

But with Nginx, even if I command `service nginx restart`, changes won't be applied:(

Why? and How can I fix this problem?

Comment: If reboot the pc, now changes are applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restart unicorn itself.  See http://unicorn.bogomips.org/SIGNALS.html

With Apache+Passenger, when you restart Apache, it restarts Passenger.  Unicorn is it's own server however and needs to be restarted/reloaded itself.

Comment: Is there any easy command to restart unicorn? I always do this to start my app `unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -D`

Comment: No idea.  I've never used unicorn.  I would imagine there is.